# Cypher Queries Endless Loop

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having some troubles with neo4j/cypher.
For instance, this query:

```
MATCH
    (n71613:Concept)-[r0:similarTo]->(n5230:Concept),
    (n5230:Concept)-[r1:similarTo]->(n90576:Concept),
    (n5230:Concept)-[r2:similarTo]->(n121858:Concept),
    (n5230:Concept)-[r3:similarTo]->(n126486:Concept),
    (n126486)-[r:similarTo]->(child:Concept)
WHERE
    (child <> n90576
    AND child <> n121858
    AND child <> n126486
    AND child <> n71613
    AND child <> n5230)
AND
    (n90576 <> n121858
    AND n90576 <> n126486
    AND n90576 <> n71613
    AND n90576 <> n5230
    AND n121858 <> n126486
    AND n121858 <> n71613
    AND n121858 <> n5230
    AND n126486 <> n71613
    AND n126486 <> n5230
    AND n71613 <> n5230)
RETURN *
LIMIT 1
```

goes in an alleged endless loop,
meanwhile running it like this doesn't:

```
MATCH
    (n71613:Concept)-[r0:similarTo]->(n5230:Concept),
    (n5230:Concept)-[r1:similarTo]->(n90576:Concept),
    (n5230:Concept)-[r2:similarTo]->(n121858:Concept),
    (n5230:Concept)-[r3:similarTo]->(n126486:Concept),
    (n126486)-[r:similarTo]->(child)
WHERE
    ('Concept' IN labels(child))
AND
    (child <> n90576
    AND child <> n121858
    AND child <> n126486
    AND child <> n71613
    AND child <> n5230)
AND
    (n90576 <> n121858
    AND n90576 <> n126486
    AND n90576 <> n71613
    AND n90576 <> n5230
    AND n121858 <> n126486
    AND n121858 <> n71613
    AND n121858 <> n5230
    AND n126486 <> n71613
    AND n126486 <> n5230
    AND n71613 <> n5230)
RETURN *
LIMIT 1
```

I don't really know what's going on here,
I found that workaround by sheer luck.

So, sometime later, I'm having a problem with endless loops again.
Almost the same query, but a different pattern:

```
MATCH
    (n0:Company)-[r0:produced]->(n1:Document),
    (n0:Company)-[r1:produced]->(n2:Document),
    (n0:Company)-[r2:produced]->(n3:Document),
    (n0:Company)-[r3:produced]->(n4:Document),
    (n0:Company)-[r4:produced]->(n5:Document),
    (n0)-[r:produced]->(child)
WHERE
    ((child <> n0) AND (child <> n1) AND (child <> n2) AND (child <> n3) AND (child <> n4) AND (child <> n5))
AND
    ((n0 <> n1) AND (n0 <> n2) AND (n0 <> n3) AND (n0 <> n4) AND (n0 <> n5) AND (n1 <> n2) AND (n1 <> n3) AND (n1 <> n4) AND (n1 <> n5) AND (n2 <> n3) AND (n2 <> n4) AND (n2 <> n5) AND (n3 <> n4) AND (n3 <> n5) AND (n4 <> n5))
AND
    ('Document' IN labels(child))
RETURN n0 AS n0_0, r0, n1 AS n1_0, n0 AS n0_1, r1, n2 AS n2_1, n0 AS n0_2, r2, n3 AS n3_2, n0 AS n0_3, r3, n4 AS n4_3, n0 AS n0_4, r4, n5 AS n5_4, n0 AS parent, r, child
LIMIT 1
```

causes an other alleged endless loop,
which I happened to "overcome" by doing this:

```
MATCH
    (n0:Company)-[r0:produced]->(n1:Document),
    (n0:Company)-[r1:produced]->(n2:Document),
    (n0:Company)-[r2:produced]->(n3:Document),
    (n0:Company)-[r3:produced]->(n4:Document),
    (n0:Company)-[r4:produced]->(n5:Document)
WHERE 
    ((n0 <> n1) AND (n0 <> n2) AND (n0 <> n3) AND (n0 <> n4) AND (n0 <> n5) AND (n1 <> n2) AND (n1 <> n3) AND (n1 <> n4) AND (n1 <> n5) AND (n2 <> n3) AND (n2 <> n4) AND (n2 <> n5) AND (n3 <> n4) AND (n3 <> n5) AND (n4 <> n5))
OPTIONAL MATCH
    (n0)-[r:produced]->(child:Document)
WITH *
WHERE
    (r IS NOT NULL)
AND
    ((child <> n0) AND (child <> n1) AND (child <> n2) AND (child <> n3) AND (child <> n4) AND (child <> n5))
RETURN n0 AS n0_0, r0, n1 AS n1_0, n0 AS n0_1, r1, n2 AS n2_1, n0 AS n0_2, r2, n3 AS n3_2, n0 AS n0_3, r3, n4 AS n4_3, n0 AS n0_4, r4, n5 AS n5_4, n0 AS parent, r, child
LIMIT 1
```

but this query causes an endless loop for the first pattern (first query I posted) (and no, not even the "labels()" trick made it work).

I just need a way to do pattern matching quickly, without having to change the query for obvious reasons.

I don't really understand what's going on here,
I hope you can shread some light and help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Please share more details like What are you trying to do with this query?

Comment: do you mean in the latter query? i'm just trying to check if a subgraph which has a root node (n0) has 6 outgoing links (with 6 different nodes) exists

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers, I don't think this is an "endless loop", but rather a large Cartesian product caused by the repeated pattern matching. Would something like [`apoc.node.degree.out`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#node-functions) be useful for your application?

Comment: i don't think so, i need to check if that very same subgraph exists in my db. the fact is, matching n0 to n5 is very fast, but adding the "child" node makes it kind of "endless". i really don't understand why. is there any other way to check if a path exists in the db?

Comment: So, if a node has your desired out-degree of the specified relationship type, that's not good enough? ... because the relationship might go to an undesired node?  ... because the same relationship type might go between two nodes more than once?

Comment: child is not different from any of n1-n5.

Comment: It's connected to n0 same as others(n1-n5), it has same label as others, same relationship type with n0 as others.

Comment: @rickhg12hs it won't work for my use case because i need, in some cases (like this one), that the child isn't linked back to one of the nodes in the path. by just counting, i cannot ensure that.

Comment: FYI, http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/ can sometimes be very helpful for showing a graph.

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks, really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching the same pattern repeatedly and creating a cartesian product.

Instead of writing multiple Match use just one. I am not clear what are you trying to achieve, If you can share the details, I can suggest to you how to write Query for it.

**EDIT:**
Try this:

```
MATCH (n:Company)-[r:produced]->(m:Document) 
WITH n, COLLECT(DISTINCT m) as ms
WHERE size(ms) = 6 
MATCH (n:Company)-[r:produced]->(m:Document) 
RETURN n, r, m 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: if i wrote just one match i wouldn't get the result i'm hoping for, that is a graph with a root node and 6 outgoing links with different 6 nodes

Comment: Do you have multiple outgoing links from the root and other nodes? I mean multiples links between root and one particular node?

Comment: Are interested in only 6 nodes? What if there are less/more number of links, like 4,5 or 7,9 etc?

Comment: yes, the root node might have different link types towards a node.
i'm interested in exact matching 6 nodes (or say N fixed nodes), not one less or one more

Comment: You should find number of distinct nodes connected to Root node for specific relationship type (here 'produced') and filter only if the count is exact 6.

Comment: this is going to work, i just need a way to figure out how to dynamically generate this query: `MATCH (n:Company)-[r:produced]->(m:Document)
WITH DISTINCT n, COLLECT(DISTINCT r) as r, COLLECT(DISTINCT m) as m
WHERE size(r) = 6
RETURN n, r, m
LIMIT 1` from my code perspective. i think i can mark it as solved

Comment: you need to replace count by size and LIMIT 1 by LIMIT 6 to return a full pattern. the solution i posted in the comment above, works almost the same way i think. anyway, is there a way to return the result in a lot of columns? i mean something like: n0, r0, n1, n0, r1, n2, n0, r3, n3, n0, r4, n4 etc by using this solution?

Comment: Don't think we can return as you are asking. Try this outside with the help of programming language.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot for your help. you made me understand a lot of things